# How to get server-side web statistics (like Webalizer) from a google cloud app engine service

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-analytics, google-cloud-platform

I have set up a google cloud web app (nodejs 10, standard) but i'm wondering how i can analyse my web traffic. I need to know where visitors are coming from.

I don't want to use a client side tool like google analytic, i need a server-side solution like webalizer.

Is this something that is already available as part of google cloud platform?

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) There is no server-side solution for App Engine Standard unless you integrate libraries into your code. 2) The data that you want is stored Stackdriver. Find an app that can process Stackdriver logs.

Comment: a way might work for you is create a Sink from Stackdriver as [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#creating_sinks) and then analyzing with BigQuery